# How to fix vs_installershell.exe has an invalid certificate?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

vs_installershell.exe has an invalid certificate. Error when trying to update, open, repair or reinstall; and now I can't open Visual Studio!

I tried the post from the Visual Studio Community but, when I click the asked update button, it loads then it stops working. [View article](http://%20https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/676241/vs-installershellexe-has-an-invalid-certificate-vs.html).

Error Messages:

1) vs_installershell.exe has an invalid certificate
2) Visual Studio 2019 has stopped working
3) Visual Studio Installer has stopped working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably due to a pending Windows update not being installed. Solution recommended by [MSDN](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/676241/vs-installershellexe-has-an-invalid-certificate-vs.html):

> Please go to windows update and make sure all pending windows update
>   are installed and reboot the computer, then go to C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer then run vs_installershell.exe
>   as administrator.

Comment: @MathewAgustinBella That update is also explicitly mentioned on the MSDN site I linked. Did my suggestion work?

Comment: After running it as administrator (https://prnt.sc/pgtbr4) then another error shows up (https://prnt.sc/pgtc3o)

Comment: @MathewAgustinBella   Did you install all pending updates and reboot your PC?

Answer (score 0):

just delete Vs_installer.exe and Vs_installershell.exe from the address below and then run Visual Studio setup again which subsequently copy the installer to the same folder :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer

then run the installer if you want !